# weighted graph problem

Tags: graph-theory

A graph with n nodes "shortest" is the sum of the edges weight of the shortest path tree to the root.minimal is the sum of the  edges weight in MST.
How Can I find the upper bound of shortest/minimal??

Comment: Please explain clearly. What is the shortest *path tree* -- it is either a path or a tree? MST will contain the root by definition. Also what makes your minimal actually minimal? Do you mean *minimal* or *minimum*?

Comment: shortest path tree is a spanning tree of a graph. for each node it contains the shortest weighted path to the root (random root).

minimal is the sum of the weighted edges. (the sum of the edges in the minimal sppaning tree)

Answer (score 1):

One obvious bound on the weight of the MST is the sum of all edges in the graph. Another is the sum of weights of *any* spanning tree.